# Local video will not loop in Firefox, but works in Chrome (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, firefox, video, frontend

So it switches the initial rain video file for a different one, but the new one doesn't even reach the length of the video before it gets stuck. Same thing with different files. The initial file works just fine, and it's 10x the size. Very confused. p2 is a text box and no, I don't know why I called it that. Works just fine in Chrome but not Firefox.

```
function phase2(){ 
            rain.src = "BloodRain2.0.mp4"
            rain.play()
            rain.loop = true;
            p2.style.display = "initial"; 
            p2.value = "Oh no...";
            phase2_tr = true; //trigger to reference phase 2 later on
            phase_def = 1.3; //update stats for phase 2
            phase_mdef = 1.2;  
            setTimeout(() =>{
                p2.style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("boss_img").src = "AKUMU2.0.jpeg";
                phase1_theme.pause();
                const phase2_theme = new Audio('phase2OST.mp3') 
                phase2_theme.play();
                phase2_theme.loop = true;
                roar.play();
                roar.loop = false;
                document.getElementById("boss_name").innerHTML = "Akumu, Origin of the Nightmare";
        
                ostbox.value = "Now playing: \n Bloodborne OST: The Hunter - Phase 2";
            }, 4000);
            setTimeout(()=>{
                const xtraThunder = new Audio("xtrathunder.mp3")
                xtraThunder.play();
                xtraThunder.loop = true;
            }, 5000);

    
        }
```

The intial file is right up top like so:

```
var rain = document.getElementById("rainbg")
rain.loop = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about removing the element like so

```
 var rain = document.getElementById("rainbg");
 document.removeChild(rain);
```

Then try your code again.